# How the average value is computed for this sine wave

Tags: definite-integrals

In the following picture,

[image]

I'm trying to compute the average value of the blue wave which represents the output of a half-wave rectifier circuit. In the book, it is $V_o \approx (1/\pi)V_s - V_D/2$ where the black wave is a sine wave. I'm not sure how the average is computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $v_0(t) = \max(v_s(t)-v_D,0)$.

In the above case, the signal $v_s$ is a $T$-periodic $\sin $ wave, you want to compute ${1 \over T} \int_0^T v_0(t) dt$.

Since $v_s$ is $T$-periodic, it follows
that $v_0$ is too, we can shift the time origin to suit the computation.

Take $v_s(t) = V_s \sin (2 \pi {t \over T})$, note that if $V_s \le V_D$, then $v_0 = 0$, so we will assume that $V_S > V_D$.

Let $t^*$ be the smallest positive time such that
$v_s(t^*) = V_D$, that is
$t^* = {T \over 2 \pi } \arcsin {V_D \over V_s}$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
{1 \over T} \int_0^T v_0(t) dt &=& {1 \over T} \int_0^{T\over 2}
 v_0(t) dt \\
&=& {2 \over T} \int_0^{T \over 4} v_0(t) dt \\
&=& {2 \over T} \int_{t^*}^{T \over 4} v_0(t) dt \\
&=& {2 \over T} \int_{t^*}^{T \over 4} (v_s(t)-V_D) dt \\
&=& {2 \over T} \int_{t^*}^{T \over 4} (V_s \sin (2 \pi {t \over T})-V_D) dt \\
&=& {2 \over T} \left [  -{T \over 2 \pi} V_s \cos (2 \pi {t \over T})-V_D t \right ]_{t^*}^{T \over 4} \\
&=& {1 \over \pi} V_S \cos (2 \pi {t^* \over T}) - {1 \over 2} V_D + 2 V_D {t^* \over T} \\
&=& {1 \over \pi} V_S \sqrt{1 - ({V_D \over V_S})^2 } - {1 \over 2} V_D + {1 \over \pi} V_D \arcsin {V_D \over V_s} \\
&=& {1 \over \pi} V_S \left[ \sqrt{1 - ({V_D \over V_S})^2 } + {V_D \over V_S}\arcsin {V_D \over V_s}\right ] - {1 \over 2} V_D  
\end{eqnarray}
If we expand this expression in a Taylor series in terms of $V_D$, then
the first two terms are ${1 \over \pi} V_S  - {1 \over 2} V_D$.

Note, from a less accurate and less computationally intensive perspective, one could approximate the output as
$v_0(t) = V_s \sin (2 \pi {t \over T}) -V_D$ for the first half cycle and $v_0(t) = 0$ for the second. This will yield the
expression ${1 \over \pi} V_S  - {1 \over 2} V_D$.

Comment: For the last paragraph, what would be the limits of the integral? Isn't from zero to $\pi$ and the whole period is $2\pi$? If I assume so, I end up with this result $\frac{1}{2\pi}[2V_s - (2+\pi)V_D]$. This is only true if I approximate $(2+\pi) \approx \pi$. Is this a valid assumption?!

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting a period of $2 \pi$, the period above is $T$. The approximation is  ${1 \over T} (\int_0^{T \over 2} (V_s \sin (2 \pi {t \over T}) -V_D) dt ) = {1 \over \pi} V_S - {1 \over 2} V_D$. The approximation in your comment is unlikely to be valid.